# How to unlink a node with python?

Tags: python, node-editor

Having a node, I want to unlink it.
My current approach is to clear all links from a desired NodeSocket:

```
my_node.inputs[0].links.clear()
```

I get a:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'clear'
```

I would think that 'links' is a NodeLinks structure, which would have 
*'clear()'* and *'remove()'*, but apparently no? I also can not simply 
`del my_node.inputs[0].links[0]`.

One approach I got working is:

```
for l in my_node.inputs[0].links:
     shader_node_tree_links.remove(l)
```

but is there a simpler way? Should one of my previous attempts work?

Comment: There is mistake in: ```
for l in output.links : if l.to_socket == input : node_tree.remove(l)
```
**node_tree.remove(l)** does'nt work. You need to use **node_tree.links.remove(l)**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `my_node.inputs[0]` is a node Socket type, and the `my_node.inputs[0].links` is a [read only list of links](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bpy.types.NodeSocket.html#bpy.types.NodeSocket.links) from this socket, so your first attempt won't work, and you have found the correct way, which is deleting the link from `node_tree.links` as follows:

```
 # remove only the desired link
 l = my_node.outputs[0].links[0]
 node_tree.links.remove(l)
```

To find a link:

```
output = my_node1.outputs[0]
input  = my_node2.inputs[0]

for l in output.links :
    if l.to_socket == input :
       node_tree.links.remove(l)
```

Also you can check for the connected node: `if l.to_node == my_node2:`

See the [DOC page](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bpy.types.NodeLink.html#bpy.types.NodeLink) for more details.